# Script does not run commands in bluetoothctl

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, bluetooth

I wrote a small script to automate the connection of my bluetooth headphones to my linux machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

bluetoothctl
wait ${!}
connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX #headphone MAC address
wait ${!}
exit
```

The script opens `bluetoothctl` but doesn't run any of the following commands.

Comment: That's just not the way shell scripts work. Each command in a shell script is run by the shell. It does not somehow send that to sub-processes. In this case, `bluetoothctl` is run by the shell and then the shell will not execute the next line of the script until `bluetoothctl` exits. Need to use something like [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) to "talk" to interactive programs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `bluetoothctl` command in shell script as follow  :

```
bluetoothctl -- command
```

or:

```
echo -e "command\n" | bluetoothctl
```

e,g:

```
bluetoothctl -- connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bluetoothctl -- pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
sleep 10
bluetoothctl -- trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
bluetoothctl -- connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
sleep 5
```

works like a charm. Its especially useful when adding "sleep" delays between `pair`, `trust` and `connect` under `bluetoothctl` to give it time to discover and setup the BT devices.

Something like

```
bluetoothctl <<EOF
pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
sleep 10
exit
EOF
```

would not work because `sleep` is not recognized as a command under `bluetoothctl`.